# Comparing/identifying namedtuple types

Tags: python

Can I identify the `namedtuple` type of an object from another package using `isinstance()` or some other call? Consider the following code for checking the type of a namedtuple:

```py
>>> vercingatorix=namedtuple('vercingatorix','x')
>>> v=vercingatorix(1)
>>> w=v
>>> isinstance(w,vercingatorix)
True
```

So far, so good. But what if the `namedtuple` is created by another package, e.g. `pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.vercingatorix`, as reported by `type()`? I tried `isinstance(w, pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.vercingatorix)` but I get an `AttributeError`. The `namedtuple` is not globally accessible (e.g. `isinstance(w, vercingatorix)`- -- `NameError`).

This is a simplified case of my problem. I have a `namedtuple` object  (representing a message) that, depending on the kind of message, has a different subclass type. I need to be able to identify the kind of message, and the simplest way to do this seems to be to look at its type. But I can't formulate a way to do this.

Comment: Why doesn't `isinstance(a, pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.class)` work? You are going to have to get a reference to the class from *somewhere*; `<class '__main__.A'>` is just a string representation of the class created by `type.__str__`, not a Python expression.

Comment: What does it mean _what if I don't have an instance of class A to compare against_ - you are not comparing against another instance of given class.

Comment: And `isinstance()` is not meant to tell you the exact type, you have `type()` for that. i.e. `isinstance()` is the prefered way, instead of comparing `type(some_instance)` with some type and with the added benefit that it also handles the inheritance.

Comment: `isinstance(a, BaseClass)` tells you if `a` is an instance of `BaseClass` or a direct, indirect or virtual subclass thereof. `type(a)` will tell you exactly which one.

Comment: @chepner It gives me an `AttributeError` and says the attribute (class name) doesn't exist.

Comment: @buran I suppose you have a point -- in my example I compared against `A`, which is a class, not an instantiation of the class -- I guess I was confused because I instantiated it for the object to compare it against. Brain glitch. I don't understand your second comment, though?

Comment: @Vercingatorix Then you are probably just using the wrong package/module name. (Or you haven't imported it.)

Comment: @martineau Yes, but what syntax do I used to write/formulate `BaseClass` for a class which `type(object)` identifies as `<class 'pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.identifier'>`? It's possible this question is peculiar to the code I'm using and I've oversimplified it.

Comment: @chepner Well, I can do a `dir(pkg1.pkg2.pkg3)` and that works. When I explicitly import `pkg1.pkg2.pkg3`, then `isinstance(a,pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.class)` still doesn't work (`AttributeError`). Although maybe I need a different path, as you suggest ... I tried another one but that didn't work, either. Maybe I'll explore this further.

Comment: Is the name `class` actually in the return value of `dir(pkg1.pkg2.pkg3)`? That would be odd, since you have to jump through some hoops to create such an attribute (`class` being a keyword and all). If not, then `pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.class` is clearly not the name of your class; I would expect something like `pkg1.pkg2.pkg3.A`.

Comment: @chepner The object in question turns out to be a `namedtuple`, now that I look at it more closely. That might explain some oddities. `dir(pkg1.pkg2.pkg3)` contains no `class` or `__class__`. It's `type()` is `<class 'module'>`. Let me update the question.

Comment: My second comment was with regards to this statement  _I need to be able to identify the kind of message, and the simplest way to do this seems to be to look at its type_ while your question is regarding `isinstance`. That's why I said that you can use `type()` to get the exact class and that `if isinstance(a, A):` is like `if type(a) == A:`, i.e. neither is going to give you the class..

Answer (score 0):

I can grab the class's name (which reveals the message type) and use that for comparison:

```py
>>> w.__class__.__name__
'vercingatorix'
```